# camel-xmljson define output types

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel-xmljson component to transform xml to json in spring. 
I have the next code in my camel-context:

```
<dataFormats>
    <xmljson id="xmljson" forceTopLevelObject="false"/>
</dataFormats>

<route id="LCG-Producer" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="activemq:to_in"/>
    <marshal ref="xmljson"/>
    <to uri="activemq:to_out"/>
</route>
```

The body to transform is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <example>
        <cadena1>aaaaaaa</cadena1>
        <entero1>1511</entero1>
    </example>
```

The problem is that the json generated is the next:

```
{
   "cadena1": "aaaaaaa", 
   "entero1": "1511"
}
```

The field "entero1" is generated as a String and it is an Integer, i mean, i need that output (without ""):

```
    {
       "cadena1": "aaaaaaa", 
       "entero1":1511
    }
```

Is there any way to define the data format?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked source code of XmlJsonDataFormat and I guess it is not possible.
However you can use same serializers to make you our processor.

For example:

(Disclaimer: the code is not efficient, it is only to give you ideas)

```
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                    JSON json=serializer.read(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                    StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();

                    JsonConfig jsonConfig=new JsonConfig(); 
                    jsonConfig.registerJsonValueProcessor("entero1", new JsonValueProcessor() {
                        @Override
                        public Object processArrayValue(Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig) {
                            return new BigDecimal(value.toString());
                        }
                        @Override
                        public Object processObjectValue(String key, Object value, JsonConfig jsonConfig) {
                            return new BigDecimal(value.toString());
                        }
                    });
                    JSONSerializer.toJSON(json, jsonConfig).write(writer);
                    writer.close();
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(writer.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this document http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html#xml xmlserializer treats all data as string, unless "type" attribute is specified on the xml element, e.g.:

```
<example>
    <cadena1>aaaaaaa</cadena1>
    <entero1 type="number">1511</entero1>
</example>
```